# extract text from image using Tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning

Apart from Image Classification and other cool application is there any way we can extract text from images using Tensorflow, Image can be any format or pdf?

Comment: For PDF, you could use pdf2txt. No OCR necessary. You are welcome.

Comment: had you find any thing for extracting text

Comment: You can explore [this](https://github.com/githubharald/SimpleHTR), [this](https://github.com/JackonYang/captcha-tensorflow) or [this](https://keras-ocr.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) may help you. Thanks!

Comment: @TFer2 the first link you mentioned for handwritten text recognition using tensorflow, is it helpful in reading normal text from an image, eg. the screenshot of this page, is it possible to extract text of this page?

Answer (score 0):

With Tensorflow you would have to train a model to detect digital or handwritten characters. The better way would be to use Opencv and pytesseract